# php : System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: php, salesforce, soap-client

Please help me to sort out this problem
I am getting this error. 
        **[faultstring] => System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object**
        I am using custom object integration for Sales force.

```
  

            require_once ('soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');
            require_once ('soapclient/SforceHeaderOptions.php');

            try {

            $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
            $mySforceConnection->createConnection("soapclient/partnerwsdl-sb.xml");
            $mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);
            // Define constants for the web service. We'll use these later
            $parsedURL = parse_url($mySforceConnection->getLocation());
            define ("_SFDC_SERVER_", substr($parsedURL['host'],0,strpos($parsedURL['host'], '.')));
            define ("_WS_NAME_", 'WebToLeadServices');
            define ("_WS_WSDL_", 'soapclient/WebToLeadServices-SB-V1.1.xml');
            define ("_WS_ENDPOINT_", 'https://' . _SFDC_SERVER_ . '.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/class/' . _WS_NAME_);
            define ("_WS_NAMESPACE_", 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/' . _WS_NAME_);


            // SOAP Client for Web Service

            $client = new SoapClient(_WS_WSDL_);
            $sforce_header = new SoapHeader(_WS_NAMESPACE_, "SessionHeader", array("sessionId" => $mySforceConnection->getSessionId()));

            $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($sforce_header));
             $sObject = new stdclass();
            $sObject->fullName = 'Sunil';
            $sObject->country = 'India';
            $sObject->budget = '1';
            $sObject->type = 'Contact';
            $sObject->dialingCode = '91';
            $sObject->emailAddress = "XXXX";
            $sObject->mobileNumber = "XXXXXXXX";
            $sObject->source = "google";
            $sObject->projectInterested = "Project";
            $sObject->capturePoint = "XXXX.php";
            $sObject->IPAddress = "XXXX";
            $sObject->webbannerSource = "google";
            $sObject->webbannerSize = "twitter"; 
              $createResponse = $client->createLeadFromWeb(array($sObject));

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo '<pre>';
            print_r($e);
            echo '</pre>';
            }
            ?>
    </pre>
```

Comment: Can you provide full exception message? Number of line, any other information - it help to understand faster what is wrong.

Comment: I am using custom web to lead services

http://radiusdevelopers.com/WebToLeadServices-SB-V1.0.xml


Its giving below error
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.WebToLeadServices.createLeadFromWeb: line 35, column 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for it 
We need to pass the variable like this with required field.
and  its working

```
$lead = new StdClass();
$lead->fullName = 'sunil';
$lead->mobileNumber = "1234567896";
$lead->emailAddress = "sunil@example.in";
$lead->source = "DIGITAL MARKETING";
$leadData = array('wl'=>$lead);
$response = $client->createLeadfromWeb($leadData);
```